# It is possible to assign value for Java Semaphore permits?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I know that Semaphore just keeps a count of available permits instead of actual permits object is used, but in the case, I hope to get each permit with a specific value. 
Below is my project which tries to get the ID for each permit(table), I know it is wrong as it only returns to the previous permits value instead of the specific value that it acquired (which I hope to assigned). 
So, is there any ways to assign value for Semaphore permits??

```
public class Table extends Semaphore{
int total_table;

public Table(int permits) {
    super(permits);
    total_table = permits;
}

public int table_id(){
    return total_table - availablePermits();
}
public void getTable(int cust_id){
    try{
        super.acquire();
        System.out.println("Customer " + cust_id + " : sit at Table-" + table_id());
    }catch (Exception e){}
}

public void leaveTable(int cust_id, int t_id){
    super.release();
    System.out.println("Customer " + cust_id + " : leaving Table-" + table_id());
}
```

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is called [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).
Both `BlockingQueue` and `Semaphore` are token containers (places in *Petri Net* terminology) and so both can be used for synchronization of parallel processes (threads). By design, `Semaphore` holds indistinguishable tokens, and `BlockingQueue` holds *colored tokens*, represented as references to arbitrary objects. `BlockingQueue::put` corresponds to  `Semaphore::release`, and  `BlockingQueue::take` corresponds to `Semaphore::aquire`.